# SDL_FreeSurface is not freeing RAM / RAM Overflowing

Tags: c++, overflow, sdl, ram, truetype

simple problem I think, but I have problem with freeing surface, cuz RAM is overflowing even if I add SDL_FreeSurface() to my code. Without this function RAM is fine. There's something more to "free" in this code?
This code is trying to make text (score for ping pong game) on the top of the screen.

```
    TTF_Init();
    TTF_Font* arial = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf", 32);
    SDL_Color msg_color = { 255,255,255 };

    char msg[128];
    sprintf_s(msg, "%d      %d", g_SCORE_P_LEFT, g_SCORE_P_RIGHT);

    SDL_Surface* messageSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(arial, msg, msg_color);
    SDL_Texture* Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(m_game_window_renderer, messageSurface);

    SDL_Rect msg_rect;
    msg_rect.x = 50;
    msg_rect.y = 50;
    msg_rect.w = 30;
    msg_rect.h = 30;

    SDL_RenderCopy(m_game_window_renderer, Message, NULL, &msg_rect);
    SDL_FreeSurface(messageSurface);
    TTF_Quit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're freeing the surface, but you're not freeing the texture that was created based on it. Add this line to the end:

```
SDL_DestroyTexture(Message);
```

You will also need to close your font:

```
TTF_CloseFont(arial);
```

It's also good practice to close SDL_TTF. Add this line just before SDL_Quit();

```
TTF_Quit();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but Textures are not using vRAM?
And another question - why program is severly slowing down only when I apply this code?

Comment: @FilipK. At the moment, you're essentially destroying and re-creating your textures, fonts, surfaces, and window every time the program loops. This is very inefficient. If you move the creation of that stuff before your program loop (e.g. `while(true){` ), and put the destruction of that stuff after that loop, you can re-use the stuff you've made.

Comment: @FilipK. I don't know why the textures wouldn't be stored in VRAM. They should almost always be created in VRAM, while the surfaces are stored in RAM. Perhaps the above fix would encourage SDL to do it?

Comment: @FilipK. what makes you think texture data isn't in vram? Besides, noone promised it'd be *only* in vram.